# Prepopulating masked textbox fields using MVC / jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, masking

Recently I have been going through a project in an attempt to sanitize several data inputs (most are primarily `Dates (mm/dd/yyyy)` or `DateTimes (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm)`.

I am using the [digitalBush Masking Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) and everything seemed to be working just as it should with empty fields. However - when I attempted to apply a masked field to a field that was bound to a ViewModel, I seemed to run into problems.

Example:

**HTML:**

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth})%>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#DateOfBirth").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:" "});
```

I was just curious if anyone had any ideas on how to implement text-box masking on a field that was being prepopulated with data from a ViewModel, such that it would appear as usual but when it was being changed it would react as a masked input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth) %>
```

You could write:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth) %>
```

and then you could decorate the corresponding view model property with the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Comment: One other quick follow-up Darin, How would I apply a specific CSS style to this editor, as I don't believe it accepts an overload for HTMLAttributes.

Comment: @Rionmonster, no it doesn't. There are two possibilities : either you wrap it in a `<div class="foo">...</div>` and then apply your rule like this : `.foo input { ... }` or you could also write a [custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx).

Comment: I found that one of the major issues that I was encountering was the plugin itself completely wiping out the data from the View. This was able to guide me to discovering the issue at hand. Thanks!